# My MacBook Air won't charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, magsafe

My MacBook Air won't charge, the MagSafe doesn't even have that green or red orange light and when it does it isn't very bright.

The **Battery Icon** on the upper right corner indicates **not charging**.

When I pull the MagSafe out of my MacBook Air it would turn-off but still it doesn't mean its charging.

I could only use my MacBook Air if I'm plugging the magSafe even if it doesn't charge. My battery is still 0%

Comment: What is the year and model number of your MacBook Air? If it is convenient, you should take it to an Apple Store to find out about the cost of battery replacement.

Answer (score 8):

Because you explain the problem perfectly, and in short:

- **The battery does not charge, and your Macbook does only work with MagSafe attached**

There's only one option what could be the problem...

**The battery is dead**, let me explain you why:

1. Your battery is ignored somehow, and your Macbook uses power directly from the MagSafe adapter. If you couldn't even use the Macbook with the cable in it, the cable could be the problem. Since it works with cable-attached, it's not.
2. You can use the macbook with cable in it as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a dead battery, you can check the status by going to `Apple Menu > About this Mac > System Information > System Report` (10.7 or later, similar but different on older OS)

Your battery could die for a lot of reasons, it's simply been used a lot, or it's been damaged, or used in environmental conditions that are outside of it's operating spec etc.  Check [this link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1519) to see what a normal cycle count should be so you can at least see if yours has died from old age if nothing else.

You don't say what model of Air it is - if it's an original one, it may have an expected cycle count of as little as 300 (and even then, to acheive that you would have needed to have used it correctly in terms of not storing it with a full or empty charge, regularly fully depleting it etc).  Batteries are weird.  I had one go on my first Macbook seemingly simply because I left it flat for a month.

[image]

Comment: press option and click on the battery icon for the condition, it's a bit easier...

Comment: Good call - you learn something new every day :)

Comment: I have the same problem but I checked the cycle count and found out I had 224, I'm using a Macbook Air 11" Mid-2013, the max cycle count was 1000 on Macbook Airs 11", after checking the link @stuffle gave me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my macbook air 3,1:

I went to system preferences/energysaver/clicked the battery tab and hit restore defaults. It started taking a charge after that.

I had completely let the battery run out while watching cartoons and I think it caused it to go into some kind of safety mode.